Gradle implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1' Too many characters error
I want to do web scraping in android application.
But I faced with a problem at the beginning.
I'm trying to add 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.18.1'dependency to my project and get the following error:
*Too many characters in a character literal ''org.jsoup:jsoup:1.18.1''*

I am using Android Studio Koala 2024.1.2, Gradle 8.7

Have are using a Kotlin based gradle configuration and in Kotlin (just like in Java)  single quotes ' are used for declaring single characters like 'a'.
Multiple characters in single quote are not allowed, therefore you are getting the error Too many characters in a character literal.
You want to declare a string not a character, thus you have to use double quotes:
implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.18.1")

See also the Gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:dependency-types
Please don't mix up Kotlin with JavaScript or Python where strings can be declared using single or double quotes.
